# Ignore case when comparing nvarchar on encrypted column

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I am trying to do a filter on a table using a column named `email`.

This column is encrypted using a DETERMINISTIC encryption_algorithm_name `AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256`. I am using a stored procedure called from a .net core application. My problem is that the comparison is not case sensitive.

I checked the collate property in `information_schema.columns` and it was `Latin1_General_BIN2`.

I tried to do the comparison with different COLLATE property(@email = Email COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) or  `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` as I saw in another post but that did not work.

I am not sure if the comparison occurs on the real or the encrypted value. Is there a way to make the comparison not case sensitive?

Comment: When you encrypt/hash a value, case is taken into consideration as they will have different binary values. If you don't want case taken into consideration then you should enforce the value to be lowercase or uppercase *before* encryption/hashing. For something like email, then putting it to lowercase before you encrypt is fine, as email addresses aren't case sensitive.

Comment: If the collation of your column is Latin1_General_BIN2, then I guess you'll have to use `WHERE @email = Email COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2`